# Telegram bots commands do not work in group chat due to the @ mention

Tags: telegram-bot

I have created and deployed a telegram bot which can perform some simple chat and analytics functions.

I have set a couple of / commands via botfathers /setcommands functionality and they all work fine.

However in group chats I have a problem, when I add the bot he works normally however the set commands that you can execute via the menu always include an @bot_name at the end of each command which invalidates them.

If I type in the command myself and remove the @mention, the commands work normally.

How can I tackle this issue, is it something I need to set in my code or in botfather?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($cmd == "/command" || $cmd == "/command@BOT_USERNAME") {
  // handle scenario
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This answer used to work for me, but it doesn't work anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to modify your code and replace the `'@your_bot'` with an empty string `''` from the command before processing it. That way you automatically handle both scenarios for each of the available commands.

Sadly, Telegram had a bug once or twice where it wouldn't register the `@your_bot` messages sent to it. Luckily that bug was live for a very short period of time.